# How to connect IDS uEye camera (ui-5490) using GigE Vision support?

Tags: matlab, camera, ids, acquisition, ueye

I have IDS camera as given in [this](https://en.ids-imaging.com/store/ui-5490se.html). GigE interface is available in camera specification. I have also added "GigE Vision Support from Image Acquisition Toolbox" to Matlab. But when I run `gigecamlist` command, it can't find any cameras. (Note: IDS camera drivers were installed to computer)

```
gigecamlist
Warning: No GigE Vision Cameras were detected. For troubleshooting device detection issues, click 
here. 

ans =

 []
```

Actually I found solution using `winvideo`:

```
imaqhwinfo('winvideo')
```

Using this command cameras can be shown and I can get preview but why `gigecamlist` does not show us cameras? Or why we can not connect using `gigecam`?

Comment: Did you follow the link MATLAB gives in the error message to troubleshoot camera connection issues?

Comment: Yes @CrisLuengo